# Restoring the bootloader and login screen of Vanilla Ubuntu after installing Ubuntu Studio

Tags: boot, unity, grub2, bootloader, plymouth

I have looked at many similar questions for a while, but I've been so far unsuccessful.

I have recently installed Ubuntu Studio after installing Vanilla Ubuntu 14.04, and I am quite new to Ubuntu, and Linux in general. Currently, my bootloader, my splash screen and my login screen are all different from vanilla Ubuntu, and I would quite like to change them to how they are in vanilla Ubuntu.

- My bootloader is black, instead of purple
- My splash screen is the Ubuntu Studio splash screen, instead of the vanilla Ubuntu splash screen
- And my login screen is the Ubuntu Studio login screen (I am new, but from what I read it may be the xcfe login screen?) instead of the Ubuntu login screen. However, when I close the lid of my laptop and reopen it, I am given the Unity login screen. I choose the Unity interface when I log in.

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to change it using `update-alternatives`, the first command will give you options to select the Plymouth theme:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

The second applies it to your current `initramfs`, so it is applied in the next restart.

Regarding the login screen, others have recommended using Unity Tweak Tool:

```
sudo apt-get intall unity-tweak-tool
```

Then, you can configure your theme on a graphical interface.

Comment: This resolved my problem with the splash screen completely, thank you! However, there is no option to change the login screen when booting in Unity Tweak Tool.